# Insert difference column in excel pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot, difference, calculation

Pivot Table

[image]

I need some help to insert column Diff to this pivot table, I currently use calculation but not success.

Comment: Could you do the calcs within or adjacent to your source data?

Comment: Hi Mark, i no have permission to edit the data source, i just connect it with pivot table and use calcs, but not  success.

Comment: I have found the method to handle it, it easy is done by duplicate the year field.